# Multiple AWS Application Load Balancers in One VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

What AWS technology is used in front of ECS services if those services are in both private and public subnets?  Multiple application load balancers?

I currently have three RESTful endpoints in three ECS clusters in private and public subnets.  At the moment I have an ALB in front of the public API:

```
VPC: "Development"
  Subnet: "Public"
    ALB: 
      ECS Cluster: "Member UX API"
      ECS Cluster: "Admin UX API"
  Subnet: "Private"
    ECS Cluster: "Management API"
  Subnet: "Data" 
    ECS Cluster: "Logging API"
    ECS Cluster: "Message API"
    ECS Cluster: "Session API"
```

Obviously, I need a single IP or endpoint in front of the multiple instances of each API.  I just don't know what that thing should be.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a single ALB in front of all the ECS clusters. Or you could have a separate ALB (or NLB) in front of each ECS cluster. You can even have multiple ALBs or NLBs in front of a single ECS cluster.

Comment: Gotcha.  So, one VPC would allow three ALBs?  For some reason I thought an ALB could only exist once in each VPC.

Comment: You can have hundreds of load balancers in a VPC. A VPC is just a private network. There is no real limitation on how many applications or load balancers or anything you can run in a VPC.

Comment: Hello @markb can these multiple ALB share the same availability zones as well as I am getting this error ```Error: error creating application Load Balancer: ValidationError: At least two subnets in two different Availability Zones must be specified
│  status code: 400, request id: 5faa9dea-331d-4baa-aea4-73211839c1c1``` when doing same

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes mutliple ALBs can share the same AZ. Your issue is you have an ALB with only a single AZ, an ALB has to be configured with at least two AZs.